# Power BI - When column is summed, only some values sum and others do not

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset for a client where they are looking for the sales of each order for orders after a certain date billed and with null values.

This is an example of what the data looks like with [Sales] set to Do Not Summarize.

| Order# | Customer | Date Billed | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1/2023 | 100 |
| 2 | Verizon |  | 150 |
| 2 | Verizon |  | -150 |
| 3 | AT&T | 1/2/2023 | 200 |
| 3 | AT&T | 1/2/2023 | -50 |
| 4 | Samsung |  | 100 |

[Date Billed] in this case is a measure:

Date Billed =
VAR Billed =
CALCULATE(
MAX(table1[Bill Date]),
KEEPFILTERS(table2[Order#])
)
RETURN
IF(
ISBLANK(
Billed
),
"",
Billed
)

This was done because the order#'s would not show in a table if there were no value for [Date Billed]. We or the client do not have access to change the model/relationships. We do know that it is a many-to-many relationship between table1[Invoice#] and table2[Order#]. So those Order#'s without Invoice#'s do not show in the table without [Date Billed] measure.

What I need is for the table to return results like:

| Order# | Customer | Date Billed | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1/2023 | 100 |
| 2 | Verizon |  | 0 |
| 3 | AT&T | 1/2/2023 | 150 |
| 4 | Samsung |  | 100 |

But what I am getting is:

| Order# | Customer | Date Billed | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1/2023 | 100 |
| 2 | Verizon |  |  |
| 3 | AT&T | 1/2/2023 | 150 |
| 4 | Samsung |  |  |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: going to add that I had to use the Date Billed measure instead of selecting "Show Items with No Data" since selecting this option did not change the results

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't seem to be with your measure directly, but I would rather say that it is with how the sales are being aggregated and displayed in the context and the presence of null or blank values in the 'Date Billed' field.

Try the following :

```
Total Sales = 
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        MyTable, 
        MyTable[Order#], 
        "TotalSales", SUM(MyTable[Sales])
    ), 
    [TotalSales]
)
```

[image]